# LocationListener is no calling onLocationChanged

Tags: android, location, listener, android-location

```
public class LocationService extends Service{

    private LocationManager locationMangaer=null;
    private LocationListener locationListener=null; 



    private static final String TAG = "Debug";
    private Boolean flag = false;
    public static String cityName=null;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();


        Log.d("Location Serive","Started");
        locationMangaer = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

        flag = displayGpsStatus();
        boolean c=isOnline();
        if(flag)
        {
            locationMangaer.removeUpdates(locationListener);
            Criteria crit2 = new Criteria();
            crit2.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            String provider2 = locationMangaer.getBestProvider(crit2, false);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), provider2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            locationMangaer.requestLocationUpdates(provider2,1, 1,locationListener);

        }
        else if(c)
        {
            locationMangaer.removeUpdates(locationListener);
            Criteria crit = new Criteria();
            crit.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
            crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
            String provider = locationMangaer.getBestProvider(crit, false); 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), provider, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            locationMangaer.requestLocationUpdates(provider,1, 1,locationListener);

        }
        else
        {
            //Nothing Available
        }
        Log.d("Internet",Boolean.toString(c));

    }




    /*net Enabled or Not*/
    public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
    /*----------Method to Check GPS is enable or disable ------------- */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private Boolean displayGpsStatus() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
        boolean gpsStatus = Settings.Secure.isLocationProviderEnabled(contentResolver, LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (gpsStatus) {
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }



    /*----------Listener class to get coordinates ------------- */
    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
          Log.d("Location Changed", "location:");
        Log.d("Latitude", Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()));
        Log.d("Longitude",Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        double p=loc.getLongitude();
        double q=loc.getLatitude();

        LocationChecker(p,q);


        }

            @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }




    }
```

From This Activtiy I called the service
But as soon as remove my application from recent apps through swipe the location listener stops working and does not show any location change update but if the app is running then it works fine.

```
 public class Dashboard extends ActionBarActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
                Intent l = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LocationService.class);
                    getApplicationContext().startService(l);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you stop service in onDestroy of your activity ?

You could also override method [onStartCommand](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)) and use [START_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) value.

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return sticky.
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

**UPDATE1**

You could start your service in a separate process. See doc : 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#proc

> If the process name begins with a lowercase character, the service
>   will run in a global process of that name, provided that it has
>   permission to do so.

for instance:

```
    <service
        android:name=".LocationService"
        android:process="myLocationService" [...] >
        [...]
    </service>
```

Comment: No I haven't stope my service
I Have tried that also the service is running but location listener has stoppend giving me any update

Comment: "Stop giving any update" because no log with latitude and longitude in logcat or no toast shown or both ?

Comment: No Actually when application is in background it can take location change and show toast or log but when I close my application the gps icon of the service get closed and its now not taking any updates until I again start the activity

Comment: How do you close app ?

Comment: By doing this you kill all application process, so service is killed, I'll update my answer

Comment: can u please give me an example because m not able to understand what has to be done

Comment: I add instance for Service in AndroidMAnifest

Comment: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED error working finw with semicolon :

Comment: [...] is a symbol to say put your specific code here. If you don't have specific code remove [...]